# Chapter name with a bar separation

Tags: titlesec, books

How can I show my chapter's titles, using **book class**, to be like this:

[image]

I've been using `titlesec` and `anyfontsize` package for its spacing and sizing with the following code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\fontsize{25}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thechapter}{.5cm}{\fontsize{21}{17}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{2cm}{1.4cm}{4cm}
```

But haven't got any idea on how to make that bar separation.

---

Addition from **Manuel Kuehner** (added a MWE)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\fontsize{25}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thechapter}{.5cm}{\fontsize{21}{17}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{2cm}{1.4cm}{4cm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: It's book class. Gonna place it in the beggining of the text.

Comment: I added a complete code example. Please provide this the next time yourself.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69330, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306889.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it. Just changed the second argument of the \titleformat to {\thechapter\hspace{.25cm}\raisebox{1.5pt}{$\bigm|$}} and it looks great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want full control on the style of the separation bar you can insert it as a `tikz` picture. In the following MWE I have used the `dotted` and `draw=gray` options only to show a possibility (you can omit them, if you prefer). You can set the distance between the chapter number and the chapter title changing the value of the `\numtitlesep` length. The separation bar will be placed in the middle. The height and the position of the bar are set empirically (they too can be automated based on the font used, but I don't think it's worth it for such a case).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\numtitlesep}
\setlength{\numtitlesep}{1cm}

\def\chapvrule{%
\tikz[overlay]{%
 \draw[
  draw=gray,
  dotted,
  line width=1.5pt,
  xshift=\dimexpr(0.5\numtitlesep)]
 (0,-7pt) -- (0,24pt);}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{25}{40}\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\thechapter\chapvrule}
  {\numtitlesep}
  {\fontsize{21}{17}\selectfont}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{2cm}{1.4cm}{4cm}

\begin{document} 
 
 \chapter{Lorem ipsum}
 
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]